# Make a custom text editor (styler) with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I have been asked to create a text editor with the following features:

- Import text from another source
- Apply styles to the text

  - Styles are predefined (for example style "Level 1" may make the text bold, green and italic.
  - One styling effect is to add characters before and after the selection so for example, **text has two stars before and after**
  - Styles are applied to full words, no partials
  - The text cannot be edited/changed, only styles should be added
- The article text must be saved in a version-ed manor, for example Editor A added these changes ____ on date / timestamp.

What is the best way to do this?

I have been playing with execCommand and this does most of what I want, except I cant seem to make the text non-editable, I'm not able to add chars before and after the selection **like this**, and I cant track individual changes.

I'm almost thinking I should make each word a label and treat them like objects but I'm having a hard time making them select-able (highlight the text with the mouse like you do in an editor).

Does anyone know of any libraries for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a part of the solution: how to select full words. My script is for textarea but you can make a few changes if you want to use div contenteditable instead.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/ypv5y06j/2/)**

```
var lastSelectStart = 0;
var lastSelectEnd = 0;

saveSelection = function(){
    lastSelectStart = document.getElementById("text").selectionStart;
    lastSelectEnd = document.getElementById("text").selectionEnd;
}

selectWords = function(){

    var divEditable = document.getElementById("text");
    html = divEditable.innerHTML;

    var start = lastSelectStart;
    var end = lastSelectEnd;

    var before = html.substring(0,start);
    var after = html.substring(end);

    var split = before.match(/[ .,;]/gi);
    var startIndex  = before.lastIndexOf(split[split.length-1]) + 1;

    split = after.match(/[ .,;]/gi);
    var endIndex = after.indexOf(split[0]);
    endIndex = end + endIndex;

    divEditable.selectionStart = startIndex;
    divEditable.selectionEnd = endIndex;
    // startIndex is where you insert your stars and
    // (endIndex + number of stars added) is where you insert your stars again
}
```

Comment: Thank you Im going to play with this today.

Comment: The only problem Im running into is that I cant add html to style the text. I need to select something and turn it blue etc. I was using an iFrame to create my own WYSIWYG I guess Ill try to combine it.